# I get wierd dim animation when backing from activity started by navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, back-stack

Process: I click on item in navigation drawer in Main activity and start new Activity, then if I click on back button or somehow restore my Main activity weird dim happens.

If I set ScrimColor of my DrawerLayout to TRANSPARENT, then animation looks normal. Otherwise I see at the end of Fade out animation a little blink (dim) from darker color to actual background (quite annoying).

If I start the same activity from normal button, the animation is good.

Do you know how to fix it?

Screen record: https://youtu.be/1A06wE1ebzQ
- Interesting thing was that while I was recording via KitKat record, sometimes the animation was looking good.

Drawer code:

```
public class DrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private String[] mMenuTitles;
  private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
  private ListView mDrawerList;
  private CharSequence mTitle;
  private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

  protected void onCreateDrawer() {
    mTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    mMenuTitles = new String[]{getString(R.string.drawer_activity1),
    getString(R.string.drawer_activity2),   
    getString(R.string.drawer_activity3)};
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor
    (getResources().getColor(R.color.black_transparent_30));
    // mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mMenuTitles));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
    ) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            setCheckedItem(mDrawerList);
            //  getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //  getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

public void setCheckedItem(ListView mDrawerList) {
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setCheckedItem(mDrawerList);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    startMyActivity(position);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

public void startMyActivity(int position) {

}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements    
ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Nobody can say with out looking at you code and images to show what the problem is. Relevant images will be helpful.

Comment: I have added Navigation drawer code and screen record.

Comment: If I start activity after Navigation drawer is closed, it works fine. I have written answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406029/open-next-activity-only-after-navigation-drawer-completes-it-closing-animation/30574535#30574535